# Apache 2.4 is running very Slow on Windows 8 - 64 bit

Tags: php, apache, windows-8, 64-bit, wampserver

I install apache 2.4 on my pc. it run very slow often. page title in Internet Explorer show "waiting for localhost" with loading icon!
installed softwares:

```
windows 8 64bit > 
            Apache2.4 64bit
            php 5 64bit
            MySQL 5 64bit
            phpMyAdmin 4
```

problem is not for mySQL ... when its shutdown , problem is still there.
I have searched and find solutions but they were not helpful.like:

- add "127.0.0.1  localhost" >>> to C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts
- add "EnableMMAP on" and "EnableSendfile on" on httpd.conf
- enable and set realpath_cache_size= 4m on php.in

any idea?

Comment: my os is Win8 x64 - how try 8bit?! - did you mean 32bit(x86)?

Comment: This was off topic = joke.

Answer (score 6):

Is this problem occuring on other browsers than Internet Explorer?

If not it might be related to Apache's [Multi-Processing Module optimized for Windows NT](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/da/mod/mpm_winnt.html). This has been named as one of the possible causes for a very unresponsive / hanging Apache.

The fix would be to add this to your httpd.conf:

```
AcceptFilter http none
AcceptFilter https none
```

See [my blog post](http://stijndewitt.wordpress.com/2014/01/10/apache-hangs-ie11/) on this topic for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I had the 64bit version of WAMP installed. I exported by databases (mySql). Uninstalled WAMP, downloaded and installed the 32bit version. Imported my databases.
The speed difference was VERY noticeable...  You might want to give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that  there is an  issue with localhost dns resolution on windows 8.
Following the instructions in this  article  did it for me:

http://othermachines.com/blog/solving-performance-issues-windows-8-wampserver-drupal