# WAMP incredibly slow over network

Tags: windows, networking, wamp

I have set up a WAMP development server on a Windows 8 machine and it works very well when accessed by `http://localhost`, however when accessing same page by IP address (whether from the same machine on which WAMP server is hosted or from different machine on the network) it is incredibly slow.

For example, a typical page takes 0.2 seconds to load through localhost, and 9 seconds to load through IP address.

Would anyone know what could be the issue?

Comment: Traffic to and from localhost uses your Network card's loopback interface -- the network traffic never actually leaves your computer. The same goes to 127.0.0.1. If you are using the IP address assigned from a DHCP server, then the traffic goes out from your NIC, to the router, and back to your computer. Does http://127.0.0.1 load as quick as http://localhost? You might try disabling IPv6 on your machine.

Comment: Yeah, 127.0.0.1 is just as quick as localhost. Disabling IPv6 - will try that now, thanks.

Comment: You can also try pinging your DHCP assigned IP address to see what the response time is. You could also run a traceroute on your IP: Windows + Q -> Type "cmd" and press ENTER. `tracert your_ip_address`

Comment: Tried disabling IPv6, unfortunately that did not help much.

Comment: Tried pinging, and response is sub 1ms...

Comment: This question might be a good read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18812213/apache-2-4-is-running-very-slow-on-windows-8-64-bit

Comment: I have kind of the same problem here. But it's only taking more than 6 secondes when accessing using a mobile device (here : ipod & ipad). Works great with chrome on another computer.